# how to select single url from multiple urls in single href using css?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZT9Y.jpg) is the image what I want to scrap. I want to scrap href of the player but in the output, I am getting two URLs for single player. One for player and other for a team. I do not want the second URL.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt4fy.jpg) is the output image.

Comment: Please refrain from using images of text/code in your questions. It disables computer parsing of questions and in general makes it more difficult for people to read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve all of the URLs and then sort through them keeping only those that begin with `/players/`. This can easily be done using a list comprehension and the `startswith` method.

```
urls = [url for url in urls if url.startswith("/players/")]
```

Where `urls` is an array of all of the urls you have retrieved.